# LTspice shows second voltage which is not supposed to show

Tags: transistors, ltspice, simulation

[image]

This schematic is a transistor (current amplifier) circuit. It is called By pass condenser.
It is a current amplifying circuit.

The graph of OUT is just same voltage graph that my book described.
But it also shows another graph which should not happen. And its graph is dotted line. What is this second graph of question mark?

Comment: That's the phase. Your AC plot is actually the magnitude of a complex number, thus you also get a phase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the phase plot, the phase in degrees is shown in the right hand axis. You get that automatically when you do an AC analysis.

If you don't want it to plot you can right click the right axis and turn it off.